# Why ROW_NUMBER() makes a difference in the results produced by this query?

Tags: t-sql

Why ROW_NUMBER() makes a difference in the results produced by this query?

```sql
select Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor
from(
    select name, occupation, row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) rowno from occupations
) src
pivot(
    max(name) for occupation in(Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor)
) as pivotable
```

Result:

```
Aamina Ashley Christeen Eve
Julia Belvet Jane Jennifer
Priya Britney Jenny Ketty
NULL Maria Kristeen Samantha
NULL Meera NULL NULL
NULL Naomi NULL NULL
NULL Priyanka NULL NULL
```

While:

```sql
select Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor
from(
    select name, occupation from occupations
) src
pivot(
    max(name) for occupation in(Doctor, Professor, Singer, Actor)
) as pivotable
```

Produces:

```
Priya Priyanka Kristeen Samantha
```

Shouldn't `select name, occupation from occupations` inside the FROM clause produce several rows just like the query with ROW_NUMBER() does? Why one produces only one record and the other all possible records? This was taken from a [HR challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem).

Answer (score 0):

When there are additional columns in the source table, the PIVOT attempts to keep them in the result set, so they will be available to be selected in the main query. See the query in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017#complex-pivot-example for a relevant example.

In this case, it would help to see the data returned by the subquery:

```
name      occupation rowno
--------- ---------- --------------------
Eve       Actor      1
Jennifer  Actor      2
Ketty     Actor      3
Samantha  Actor      4
Aamina    Doctor     1
Julia     Doctor     2
Priya     Doctor     3
Ashley    Professor  1
Belvet    Professor  2
Britney   Professor  3
Maria     Professor  4
Meera     Professor  5
Naomi     Professor  6
Priyanka  Professor  7
Christeen Singer     1
Jane      Singer     2
Jenny     Singer     3
Kristeen  Singer     4
```

Imagine that there is a column `rowno` that is corresponds to the row number. In the first row we have Aamina as the first doctor (alphabetically), Ashley as the first professor and so on. In the second row we have Julia as the second doctor, Belvet as the second professor and so on. Because there are only three doctors, we have a NULL in the first column of the forth row.

In the second query, we just get `max(name)` for each occupation.

Comment: Thanks for answering Razvan. There is a third column `rowno` yes, but even without this column the result set still has the same number of rows. Why pivot doesn't take into account the remaining rows if I take the `rowno` column logic out of the query? That's what I don't get.

Comment: The PIVOT clause executes before the main SELECT clause, considering just the contents of the PIVOT clause and of the FROM clause. See also: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-what-it-and-what-it-means-you and https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/logical-query-processing-clause-and-pivot.